# LockMode in EJB3 Persistence NamedQuery

Tags: persistence, ejb-3.0, named-query, pessimistic-locking

How do we specify LockMode in EJB3 Persistence NamedQuery? I want to add Pessimistic LockMode to my existing select so that I can update if necessary but surprisingly Query object doesnot have setLockMode(xxx) method ( My understanding was if JPA,  asubset of EJB3 persistence, exposes setLockMode, EJB3 persistence should have the method available too).

```
Query query = em.createNamedQuery("findOptoutStudent");
query.setParameter("optoutIndicator", optoutIndicator);
List<Student> students = query.getResultList();
return students.get(0);
```

I would assume I dont have to change the query manually to "select for update".

Thanks
Kevin

Answer (score 0):

Pessimistic Lock Mode :

- `PESSIMISTIC_READ` which represents a shared lock. Lock request fails when another entity manager has acquired `PESSIMISTIC_WRITE`.
- `PESSIMISTIC_WRITE` which represents an exclusive lock. Lock request fails when another entity manager has acquired either of the locks on the object.

Applying lock on the object

```
entityManager.lock(object, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_READ)
```

Releasing the lock afterwards

```
entityManager.lock(object, LockModeType.NONE)
```

Comment: Can I apply a lock to the object retrieved by NamedQuery? Or does it have to be the object returned by em.find only? I have something like: Query query = em.createNamedQuery("findRecords");
  query.setParameter("incomingInd", incomingInd);
   query.getResultList().get(0);

Comment: Yes, you can apply lock mode to NamedQuery by an optional element - "lockMode" in its definition.

Comment: The version required for this is JPA 2.0,