# JPA lock entity for reading

Tags: java, jpa, transactions

I have I code:

```
public static Computation findByDateAndPaymentSystem(EntityManager em, Calendar date, PaymentSystem paymentSystem) throws SCException {
        Query query = em.createNamedQuery("Computation.findByDateAndPaymentSystem");
        query.setParameter("date", date);
        query.setParameter("ps", paymentSystem);
        List<Computation> computationList = query.getResultList();
        if (computationList != null && computationList.size() > 0) {
            if (computationList.size() == 1) {
                return computationList.get(0);
            } else {
                throw new SCException("Not unique result in computation for date '"
                        + new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").format(new Date(date.getTimeInMillis())) + "' and paymentSystem = '"
                        + paymentSystem.getShortName() + "'");
            }
        } else {
            Computation computation = new Computation();
            computation.setDate(date);
            computation.setComputationState(ComputationState.CREATED);
            computation.setPaymentSystem(paymentSystem);
            em.persist(computation);
            return computation;
        }
    }
```

The main Idea is that I should have one computation instanse per date and payment system.
But if this method is called in two diferent transactions, then possible next scenarios:
First transaction check, if there no computation for this date and create computation but still not commit created computation, another transaction check and also create computation, then both transactions commit. Thus there will be two computations per one date.

How prevent it?

Comment: If a combination of data and payment system is a unique constraint in your DB then you will never be able to insert duplicate computations

Comment: Can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839069/lockmode-in-ejb3-persistence-namedquery/8083379#8083379 for Pessimistic locking on entity.

Answer (score 1):

`Computation.date` and `PaymentSystem` combination should be unique (constraint) then second insert will fail or you could try merge multiple entries if you find them. Solution depends on your usecase and transaction strategy and settings.

Comment: Is there any way create unique constraint in JPA on two fields. It is required because, I generate shema of db from JPA entities.